# Modelling two dependent many-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

I have a user who may have 0 or more foo's and bar's. Here is a diagram:

[image]

Each foo has a unique integer `ord`.

If a user has a bar, then this implies that he has a foo with `ord=1`. A user may not have foo with `ord=1` without a bar.

My thought how to avoid logical inconsistencies is to simple never insert any `foo_user` relationship with `ord=1`. However when I want to query the foo of a user with smallest `ord` I need to do this a bit complicated like this:

- 1. Query: Check if bar relationship exists. If it does, get foo with `ord=1`
- 2. Query: If no bar bar relationship exists, get foo with smallest `ord` column.

Is there maybe a more convenient database structure for this scenario?

Comment: If a user has a bar, is that associated with a specific foo? Can a user have 10 bars but only 3 foos?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ well they are associated in the sense, that if a user has a bar he must have the unqiue foo with `ord=1`. Its possible that a user has 10 bars but only 3 foos.

Answer (score 1):

Schematically:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id, 
                    name,
                    PK (id));

CREATE TABLE user_foo (user_id,
                       foo_id,
                       PK (user_id, foo_id),
                       FK (user_id) REF users (id),
                       FK (foo_id) REF foo (id));

CREATE TABLE foo (id, 
                  name,  
                  ord,
                  PK (id),  
                  KEY (id, ord));

CREATE TABLE foo_bar (foo_id,  
                      ord AS (1) VIRTUAL,  
                      bar_id,
                      PK (bar_id, foo_id),
                      FK (foo_id, ord) REF foo (id, ord),
                      FK (bar_id) REF bar (id));

CREATE TABLE bar (id,  
                  name,
                  PK (id));
```

> One foo may also have many users so the pivot tables are necessary.

Taken into account.

> foo and bar are ManyToMany relations

Taken into account.

Comment: Thank you for this proposal. However its possible that 2 users have the same foo but different bars. Foo and bar are in general independet. They only have the logical implication described in the OP.

Comment: @Adam *Foo and bar are in general independet.* It is critical. Add this info into a question text. Additionally: does a user can have multiple bars? if so, does each bar must have its own foo with ord=1, or it's enough to have one such foo for to accept any count of bars?

Comment: A user can have multiple bars. Sorry for not being clear enough, this is what I meant with `I have a user who may have 0 or more foo's and bar's.`. The condition is that the user should have one foo with ord=`1` to accept any count of bars. It would also not be possible that a user has multiple foo's with ord=`1` because ord is unique.

Comment: @Adam Oh... it's bidirectional check... but MySQL ignores CHECK constraints... so the only way is to use trigger logic. Q1: If you want to delete user reference to a foo with ord=1, you will delete all references to all bars for this user, or you will eject this foo reference deletion until all bars references deleted explicitely? Q2: Maybe better way is to realize all logic as a server one (as stored procs) restricting direct (by query) edition of these tables?

Comment: to Q1,Q2: at the moment I do not insert any foo references for a user with `ord=1`. I handle it with server logic. So if I want all foo's from the user, I get all foo's that are stored as related in the DB and then I check if the user has any bar's, and if he has any, I add the foo with `ord= 1` to the foo collection of the user. Its acceptable, but I was wondering if there is maybe a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: @Adam Server logic (I think so) is the best solution. Especially if ALL data modifications in these tables are available only via SPs (the user grants SELECT permissions only, and SPs grants RW permissions using SECURITY DEFINER).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't missing any relationships between foo and bar, then I think you may be mixing your entity-relationship model with your business logic's restrictions.

An user has many foos, many bars, and vice versa. So far, so good. Checking wether a foo with `ord=1` exists or not is your db engine's responsibility, not your e-r model's